# Odoo 14: mobile app development to communicate my web app

Tags: python, android, iphone, mobile, odoo

I want some guidance related to mobile app development using Odoo framework (if I can or i can use my custom app in mobil or i misunderstood) for Android and iPhone. I am testing using Postman. I can login successfully from Postman using json type login credentials in Body. but failed to get into the GET method, my Contol file is as below. used session_id from Cookies and my url is: http://127.0.0.1:8069/get_brands

showing this when trying to access above url (i have only 1 database):

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": null,
    "error": {
        "code": 404,
        "message": "404: Not Found", .... }
```

Is there any other requirements to achieve these 4 methods GET/POST/PUT/DELETE ?

if i create an interface for mobile app like my web app and just access it via mobile, is it ok or there is/are different things to learn ? if it is, please provide the link to the guide to create a custom mobile app OR there is any app exists which i can customize and use as part of my app like inheritance in odoo framework?

Control File ( tests/constollers/controllers.py ):

```
from odoo import http 
from odoo.http import request

class Testapi(http.Controller):
    @http.route("/get_brands", type='json', auth='user')
    def get_brands(self):
        brands_rec = request.env['tests.brands'].search([])
        brands = []
        for rec in brands_rec:
            vals = {
                'id': rec.id,
                'name': rec.name,
            }
            brands.append(vals)
        print('Brands... ', brands)
        data = {'status': 200, 'response': brands, 'message': 'Success'}
        return data
```

Please help how i can develop a mobile app for end user / employees login page and other mobile UI for query, data entry, change password etc. or any link(s) for guidance to achieve.
regards